# SQL reordered words

Tags: sql, oracle

I've recently started my SQL adventure. I was asked to write query which will put the title after the name of person. Title is part of name record. So if somebody surname is 'De Johnson' i need to make 'Johnson (de)' out of it. I need to select only names which contain two words (titled). I have found correct solution to this problem, here is the query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(naam, INSTR(naam,' ')+1) ||  ' (' || LOWER(SUBSTR(naam, 1, INSTR(naam, ' ') -1)) || ')' 
FROM medewerkers 
WHERE naam like '% %';
```

Now is my question, is it possible to make it more verbose? I'm really more into using CONCAT  in place of || etc. I don't understand concept of mixing verbosity of SQL with sings. I know that this query doesn't have any sense since SQL is not used to format the output, but I'm doing it for school (they can't teach even things as easy as SQL).

Comment: Note that you can do this nicely with `regexp_replace(naam, '^(\S+)\s+(.*)$', '\2 (\1)')` and you can then leave out the `where` clause.

Comment: It is normal to use || . CONCAT will be ugly here.

Comment: It is better to learn to use || and to "find it the normal way" to concatenate. In Oracle, `concat()` can **only** take two arguments (only Oracle knows why); if you must concatenate four strings, you would need to use `concat()` three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of turning this into an equivalent `CONCAT` expression, I would suggest a solution that would also:

- Move more little words to the end on the condition that they do not start with a capital, except for the first one. For example: "Van den Heuvel" would become "Heuvel (Van den)";
- Trim spaces from the beginning and the end: this will avoid strange effects on names that were stored with spaces at the start or the end.
- Return a name unchanged if it has no words to move into brackets. This is useful, as you can then exclude the `where` clause and have all the names in the result set.

For this task, regular expressions come in handy:

```
select regexp_replace(trim(naam), '^(\S+(\s+[^A-Z]\S*)*)\s+(\S.*)$', '\3 (\1)')
from   medewerkers
```

The last argument of the function is quite readable in showing the format that is being produced when there is a match.

NB: Depending on language settings (namely NLS_SORT, with case-insensitive sort), it might be necessary to add more arguments to `preg_replace` to enforce case-sensitivity:

```
select regexp_replace(trim(naam), '^(\S+(\s+[^A-Z]\S*)*)\s+(\S.*)$', '\3 (\1)', 1, 0, 'c')
from   medewerkers
```

Here are some test cases:

```
select id, naam,
       regexp_replace(trim(naam), '^(\S+(\s+[^A-Z]\S*)*)\s+(\S.*)$', '\3 (\1)')
          as corrected
from   (select 1 id, 'De Ridder' as naam from dual union
        select 2,  ' de Meester' from dual union
        select 3, 'Smits' from dual union
        select 4, 'Vandenborre ' from dual union
        select 5, 'Van den Borre' from dual union
        select 6, ' van der Meulen' from dual union
        select 7, 'van ''t Oosten' from dual union
        select 8, 'Van de Walle-Van der Meulen' from dual)
order by id;
```

Outputs:

```
id | naam                        | corrected
---+-----------------------------+------------------
 1 | De Ridder                   | Ridder (De)
 2 |  de Meester                 | Meester (de)
 3 | Smits                       | Smits
 4 | Vandenborre                 | Vandenborre
 5 | Van den Borre               | Borre (Van den)
 6 |  van der Meulen             | Meulen (van der)
 7 | van 't Oosten               | Oosten (van 't)
 8 | Van de Walle-Van der Meulen | Walle-Van der Meulen (Van de)
```

Comment: I don't get the same result (id 5,6 and 8)

Comment: While this is certainly a good solution (and may help other forum members in the future), it is doubtful that it will help the OP who explained clearly he is just starting to learn Oracle and SQL. Also, it does NOT achieve one of the requirements; the OP had a `LOWER()` in his solution, which appears to be intentional, not reproduced in this solution.

Comment: @Mottor, that is strange, it returns that result in my set-up: Oracle 12c.

Comment: Oracle 12.1.0.2.0   German Germany returns for 5 'den Borre (Van)' . The same with Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 German Germany

Comment: I see that the default for the case-sensitivity setting [depends on NLS_SORT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm) parameter. So you would have to enforce it with 'c' in the 5th argument of `regexp_replace`. I will update my answer accordingly.